# Does the Cpython VM execute a C code for every opcode?

Tags: python, python-internals

I have read that some VM's convert the bytecode into machine code. But I heard that Cpython VM is slightly different. I was reading [here](http://tech.blog.aknin.name/2010/04/02/pythons-innards-introduction/) that the python VM *"executes a short piece of C code matching the opcode*" Does that mean that when a Cpython interpreter is 'executing' a python byte code, ultimately ( after a lot of stuff ) it invokes different C programs which are in turn executed by the processor? Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: The easiest way to think of it is that it invokes different C functions which are in turn executed by the processor. In fact, the original quote stating that the VM *executes a short piece of C code matching the opcode* is quite correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does not invoke different programs. The CPython [interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_%28computing%29) is a C program. For every opcode it calls one of its own functions. Those functions are themselves already compiled to machine code since the interpreter is a compiled program.

That CPython does not convert the opcodes to machine code just means that it lacks a [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) to native code, such as a [Just-In-Time compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) (JIT) or ahead-of-time compiler.

A compiler translates a bunch of opcodes to machine codes that you can then execute directly on the CPU. CPython instead reads one opcode at a time and reacts to it.

Comment: Note that converting the opcodes to machine code doesn't imply JIT, the same could be done by an ahead-of-time compiler such as Cython. JIT does allow for more aggressive optimizations by inspecting usage patterns at run-time.

Comment: You are right. I still hope this helps clarifying the bigger picture: the difference between a compiler and an interpreter.

Comment: Sure, and there's always room for improvement. :) For example, the second paragraph could refer to a "compiler to native code". The term JIT defines *when* a compiler is run, not what its output is - let's not add to the confusion by conflating the two.

Answer (score 4):

The CPython interpreter *is* a program (written in C, compiled to machine code) that is executing Python byte code. The interpreter is essentially a very big switch statement which does different things for every different opcode. You can see how that works [in the source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Python/ceval.c#l1357).

For example, the code that runs for the `BINARY_ADD` opcode (e.g. `a + b`) is the following:

```
TARGET(BINARY_ADD) {
    PyObject *right = POP();
    PyObject *left = TOP();
    PyObject *sum;
    if (PyUnicode_CheckExact(left) &&
             PyUnicode_CheckExact(right)) {
        sum = unicode_concatenate(left, right, f, next_instr);
        /* unicode_concatenate consumed the ref to v */
    }
    else {
        sum = PyNumber_Add(left, right);
        Py_DECREF(left);
    }
    Py_DECREF(right);
    SET_TOP(sum);
    if (sum == NULL)
        goto error;
    DISPATCH();
}
```

Note that this uses many preprocessor functions to make this more read- and writable. In this example, it essentially pops two objects from the stack, checks if they are strings, and otherwise calls the CAPI function `PyNumber_Add` which then calls the underlying `__add__` or `__radd__` functions for the objects. And the result is then pushed to the stack.